# DirectX Back Buffer code in C++

Tags: buffer, directx-11

```
            void D3DApp::OnResize()
            {
                assert(md3dImmediateContext);
                assert(md3dDevice);
                assert(mSwapChain);

                // Release the old views, as they hold references to the buffers we
                // will be destroying.  Also release the old depth/stencil buffer.

                ReleaseCOM(mRenderTargetView);
                ReleaseCOM(mDepthStencilView);
                ReleaseCOM(mDepthStencilBuffer);


                // Resize the swap chain and recreate the render target view.

                HR(mSwapChain->ResizeBuffers(1, mClientWidth, mClientHeight, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, 0));
                ID3D11Texture2D* backBuffer;
                HR(mSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&backBuffer)));
                HR(md3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(backBuffer, 0, &mRenderTargetView));
                ReleaseCOM(backBuffer);
```

I am having a bit of trouble understanding exactly what this code is actually doing. I think it is getting the current back buffer storing the buffer in memory and then rendering it to the screen again? What could be in the contents of the buffer that is gotten? I am very confused. My program is using an 800 x 600 pixel window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the function name point out, it just Reset the backbuffer and the rendertarget, and this function should be called whenever a render window is resized.

```
HR(mSwapChain->ResizeBuffers(1, mClientWidth, mClientHeight, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, 0));
```

In an DirectX application, we always set the backbuffer size same as the window size, so when the window size changed, we should update the backbuffer size accordingly, otherwise your scene will be stretched.

```
ID3D11Texture2D* backBuffer;
HR(mSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&backBuffer)));
HR(md3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(backBuffer, 0, &mRenderTargetView));
ReleaseCOM(backBuffer);
```

The render target was based on the backbuffer which in turn should be updated.